# Visibility of a default constructor in Java 11?

Tags: java, visibility, default-constructor

What is the visibility of a default constructor in Java11?
This is different from what is the default visibility of a constructor.

Comment: what's stopping you from checking it out yourself?

Comment: ^ Maybe, but he's asking about Java 11 specifically.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi: There's a difference between "the access of a member declared without a specific access modifier" and "the access of a default constructor supplied by the constructor".

Comment: Same as in all other Java versions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The visibility of the default constructor depends on the access modifier of the class, as stated in the java specification [Chapter 8. Classes - 8.8.9. Default Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9):

> The default constructor has the same access modifier as the class, unless the class lacks an access modifier, in which case the default constructor has package access (§6.6).